# delete duplicate data based on two group by columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a Sql table which have some duplicate data

```
id  T_PSProjectId   T_CodePattern   T_NCR
1   0000130586  3MEXCM  NULL
2   0000131771  3MEXTPS NULL
3   0000131771  3MEXTPS 123456
4   0000130586  3MRA    NULL
5   0000130586  3MRAS   NULL
6   0000130586  3MT1    NULL
7   0000130586  3MT1    555
8   0000131176  3MT1    NULL
9   0000131190  3MT1    NULL
10  0000130584  3MT1    NULL
11  0000130584  3MT1    333000
12  0000130584  3MT1S   NULL
13  0000131755  3MT1S   NULL
14  0000130586  3MT1S   NULL
15  0000130586  3MT1S   550000
16  0000129495  3TMEU   NULL
17  0000131186  3TTHS   NULL
18  0000130583  3UA1P   NULL
19  0000130584  3UEXCESC    NULL
20  0000130584  3UEXCESCS   NULL
21  0000130583  3UEXCI  NULL
22  0000130583  3UEXCIS NULL
```

As you can see row 3 and 4 has same values for column T_codepattern
So i want to remove those row who have duplicate combination of columns T_PSProjectId+T_CodePattern and have T_NCR null value

Eg : from row 2 and 3 ..it should remove 2nd row
from row 6th and 7th , it should remove 6th row

I mean delete row that has same 2nd and 3rd column value with no value in 4th column.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice feature of SQL Server is the ability to have "updatable" CTEs.  That means that we can identify the rows in a `with` statement, and then use it in the delete.

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by T_PSProjectId, T_CodePattern) as cnt
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where cnt > 1 and T_NCR is null;
```

What this is doing is counting the number of rows that have the same values of `T_PSProjectId` and `T_CodePattern` using the window function `count(*)`.  The `deletion` statement then deletes rows where there are duplicates and the third column has a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
    This logic might resolve your query    


    DECLARE
  lv_dup_check NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN
  ( SELECT * FROM avrajit
  )
  LOOP
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO lv_dup_check
    FROM avrajit -- to check whether duplicate exist or not
    WHERE name =rec.name
    AND salary = rec.salary;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_dup_check);
    IF rec.department IS NULL AND lv_dup_check > 1 THEN -- if duplicate exists and the 3rd col null
      dbms_output.put_line ('deleted row'||' '||rec.salary);
      DELETE
      FROM avrajit --delete the 3rd null column with same value
      WHERE name      =rec.name
      AND salary      = rec.salary
      AND department IS NULL;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```